# How to create external storage on subdomain or other domain in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have my project and serve it on domain `https://example.com` and I try to store my files on external storage on subdomain `https://storage.example.com`, because it is good solution for `load balancer` in future. 
In `config/filesystem.php` I change driver from `local` to `ftp`, then connect to it, but when I try to create or get URL path I recive error like `"This driver does not support retrieving URLs."` or `"Impossible to create the root directory"`.

There is my `FTP driver` config:

```
    'ftp' => [
      'driver'   => 'ftp',
      'host'     => '78.xxx.xx.xxx',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'root'     => '/',
      'url' => env('APP_STORAGE').'/'
    ]
```

Also I try do it with `Public driver`, but there are no effect...

```
    'public' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      // 'root' => storage_path('app'),
      'root' => env('APP_STORAGE').'/storage',
      'url' => env('APP_STORAGE').'/storage',
      'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
```

How I can solve my issue? And may be there are some other driver(`'public'`, `'custom'`) or method to solve it? And what the easiest way to configurate it. Thanks.